# Splitting polygon into multiple fixed-width polygons along edge in R?

Tags: polygon, r, splitting, vector-grid

I have a polygon and would like to spit into grid with fixed width along with one edge. The result will look like the figure below.

Are there algorithm to achieve my target? My language is R, but welcome to any other languages.

[image]

Comment: The PostGIS function ST_Split should accomplish this, see here: http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_Split.html . In order to automate this we might need more information though (distance between lines, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The distance between lines are fixed as a user input which could be any values.

Comment: How will you determine the edge along which you make the split?

Comment: I used the first two points to split polygon.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I implement a method to split polygon along the first two points using R. See function way_points here: https://github.com/byzheng/missionplanner/blob/master/global.R

Comment: Please at least include the code (or relevant parts of it) and some description of the algorithm you came up with!